# will data sent/received through a socket written in different languages be understood both ends?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, sockets

If i use a socket to connect two programs(c++ and java script using node.js in my case) written in different languages. will the inputted data come out the same the other end ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.It is possible to achieve that. You will have to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data from the client side and send the serialized data to the server. On the server side de-serialize the received data to get the original data structure.

There are multiple libraries which facilitate this. [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) is one such example. There are other libraries like Avro, Protobuf etc. You can experiment with a few of them and find out which best suits your requirements.

These libraries generally use an [Interface Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) to define the interface which may include services and data structures. Then they can generate code in multiple languages for you to use the interface.

For the record, I have personally used thrift to communicate between a C++ server and Javascript client. It works fine.